# Should I use exit(1) or abort() for invalid inputs in C library functions?

Tags: c, error-handling, exit, abort

I am coding a small C function for a math library. This C function takes a positive integer as input and reports errors if the input is nonpositive. I am considering two different kinds of ways to exit in cases of invalid inputs -- exit (1) or abort(). Which one below should I use?

```
void foo(int x){
   if (x<0) {
       printf ("Input should be a positive number\n");
       exit (1);
   }
}
```

or

```
void foo(int x){
   if (x<0) {
       printf ("Input should be a positive number\n");
       abort();
   }
}
```

Comment: `exit 1;` is not valid C. Do you mean `exit( 1 );`?

Comment: neither, a library should not crash an app. It should report the error somehow, return an error code, set errno , something polite

Comment: also consider making the argument `unsigned` if it's always supposed to be positive.

Comment: And note that emitting error messages to `stdout` is not polite.  If you *must* emit a diagnostic, then at least have the decency to write it to `stderr`.

Comment: Libraries don't usually print their own error messages.

Comment: Libraries should never abruptly terminate on error, although there are circumstances in which a clearly named library function might not return. (`void log_and_die(const char* fmt, ...) __attribute__((noreturn))` might be a reasonable prototype for a library function.) But you should practically never use `abort()`, not even in `main()`; the only reason to use it is when the execution environment is so messed up that registered cleanup functions might cause damage. (And, no, I don't have an example of that.)

Comment: @pm100 For the record, widely used libraries still issue abort(). An example is GNU Scientific Library (GSL): "The default behavior of the GSL error handler is to print a short message and call abort()." See https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/err.html#error-handlers

Comment: @pm100 I don't completely agree. Many functions in the C library will crash on invalid inputs. Pass a NULL pointer to strlen for example. It does not signal an error. It's design by contract. If your function says clearly passing invalid inputs is undefined, then the users should take care to pass valid inputs and *error check them before passing them to the function*.

Answer (score 1):

Be polite

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int x){
   if (x<0) {

      // maybe do this - but probably not
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid value");
      errno = EINVAL;
   }
}
```

or

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x){
   if (x<0) {
      // maybe do this - but probably not
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid value");
      errno = EINVAL;
      return 0 ; // falsish
   }
   ....
   return 1; // truish
}
```

Comment: If we want the caller to see `EINVAL`, I'd do the `fprintf` first [even though if there is no error in it, it won't change `errno`] as a safety.

Comment: @CraigEstey done,

Comment: It is traditional in C libraries to return a negative error code for an error and a positive (>=0) value for success.  Sometimes always just -1 for error (with errno for detail) and sometime different negative values for different errors.  This is tricky for functions that might want to normally return a negative value, or might want to return unsigned to return very large values >INT_MAX

Comment: @ChrisDodd   Out of curiosity: why returning a positive means success but exit (1) means failure?

Comment: @zell: because for historical reasons, the arguments to exit can only be 0..255 (8 bits unsigned), so 0 means success and anything else is failure.  Its common actually to use exit(-1) for (general) failure, which effectively becomes exit(255).